# Is there a way to connect to SFTP server without password or private key reference

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch, j2ssh

I want to upload file over an SFTP server without password authentication. Here I don't want to use private key either.
My public key is already shared to the destination SFTP server. And I can login to it by using username@hostname as url from filezilla without password or private key reference.i want to achieve the same from java code.
I have explored j2shh, maverick and jsch APIs also but every where password or private key is required for authentication. Is there any way I can connect to the server by using username@hostname only from java code?

Comment: So why is your *"public key is already shared to the destination SFTP server"*, if you do not not need to use any authentication? Show us verbose FileZilla log file proving that no authentication takes place.

Comment: Hey @MartinPrikryl, I'm quite new to this concept. So you are saying FileZilla internally refers to the generated private key in my system, and interactive logon method is similar to "save password" concept?

Comment: I do not know, that's why I asked you for a log file. But it's quite probable.

Answer (score 0):

The post following will be your help.

- [OpenSSH Server - anonymous account](https://superuser.com/questions/1152645/openssh-server-anonymous-account)
- [公開鍵なし/パスワードなしでSSHログインする設定](https://qiita.com/FGtatsuro/items/4893dfb138f70d972904)

This, in a nutshell, SSH server permits client users to login without password. It means users need to request username and hostname at least.